# Como adicionar uma chave-valor em um dicionário?

Tags: python, string, sintaxe, dicionário, concatenação-de-string

Quero adicionar termos a um glossário organizado em forma de dicionário, requisitado por uma atividade, mas estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro que não consigo identificar o porque dela.

```
   glossario = {
    'concatenar': 'Concatenar é a junção de 2 cadeias de caracteres'
        ' e que dá origem a uma nova string' +
        ' que é formada pela junça das 2 partes.',
        'identar': 'Indentar é o recuo do texto em relação a sua margem',
    'array': 'Arrays são estruturas de dados' +
            ' semelhantes às listas do Python',
    'string': 'String é um objeto iterável.',
    }
for palavra, significado in set(glossario.items()):
    print(palavra.title() + ":" + "\n" + significado + '\n')
    
glossario['sequência'] = 'Sequências são coleções ordenadas embutidas:' + 
    'strings, listas, tuplas e buffers.'
```

e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
> glossario['sequência'] = 'Sequências são coleções ordenadas embutidas:' +
>                                                             ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: E pra que precisa fazer essa concatenação sem sentido?

Comment: para respeitar a PEP 8 e não ultrapassar os 79 caracteres por linha

Comment: E não seria melhor respeitar o bom senso?

Comment: glossario['sequência'] = 'Sequências são coleções ordenadas embutidas:' +str('strings, listas, tuplas e buffers.')   isso pode te ajudar?

Comment: @jeferson.cardoso O problema é que o *statement* continua na linha seguinte - veja a resposta abaixo - e `'strings, listas, tuplas e buffers'` já é uma string, usar `str` em volta não muda nada - na verdade é redundante...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não deve forçar uma concatenação só para quebrar a linha, deve indicar que a linha continua logo abaixo, para isso usa-se o `\` para indicar que é a mesma linha mesmo tendo uma quebra:

```
glossario['sequência'] = 'Sequências são coleções ordenadas embutidas:' \
    'strings, listas, tuplas e buffers.'
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/od2d5K). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fhyjdjgt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Multiline.py).

Comment: muito obrigado! não conhecia este recurso